# How can I get specific object and its index that was changed from $watch Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs-directive, watch

I get array of objects from API that is updated every 2 seconds. I have $watch that is looking for any changes in this array. I need to know what is element or elements are changed and their index, in order to set background color to these elements which were changed.
Thanks in advance.

```
$scope.$watch('recentUpdates', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if(oldValue != newValue && newValue != null){
    $scope.recentUpdates= newValue;
    console.log(newValue)
    setColor(newValue) ;
}else{
    console.log('hey, value is not changed!');
}
```

});

SetColor function need to get object and index of an element in order to update its color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume there can be more than one change per cycle.  So, you can just cycle through the array looking for changes.  I also assume that the length of the array doesn't change.

```
$scope.$watch('recentUpdates', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  for (var i=0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
    if (newValue[i] !== oldValue[i]) {
      console.log(newValue[i]);
      setColor(newValue[i], i) ;
    }
  }
});
```

You then pass the new value and the position to your setColor function.  I also removed `$scope.recentUpdates= newValue;` as there was no reason to do this.

You could also use `angular.forEach` to loop through the array if you preferred.

Comment: Thank you for answer and explanation